# The problem is, when converting into dates, the NULL values are replaced by NA

Tags: r

The dataset that I am trying to convert from factor to date in r program, has a column which contains `NULL` and Date values. I tried to convert as follows

```
          as.Date(data$Variable_42,format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

data before conversion

```
NULL
NULL
14/01/2014
```

data after conversion

```
NA
NA
14-01-2014
```

The problem is, when converting into dates, the `NULL` values are replaced by `NA`. I tried to replace `NA` values back to `NULL` but didn't work.

Comment: I think it is better to keep it as `NA` instead of a `"NULL"` If we really want to change the `NA` to unquoted `NULL`, the wrap it as a `list`, but it would make it so difficult in processing later

Comment: How do you even get NULLs into a data.frame? Are these just strings that read "NULL"?

Comment: What is the actual problem? Put differently: why is it a problem for you that unspecified dates are represented as `NA`? This is in fact the correct representation; `NULL` would be incorrect here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The actual problem is the "NULL" values are of type characters not actually a NULL. I decided to have them as NA Values. Thanks Very much for the response.

Comment: @iod Yes, the "NULL" values are Characters.